# C# MongoDB Driver With Support For Replica Sets

Tags: c#, mongodb, scalability, mongodb-.net-driver, database

Is there a C# MongoDb Driver which supports replica sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a testing branch of mongodb-csharp with support for Replica Sets.

Links:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://github.com/lanwin/mongodb-csharp/tree/1.6_prep&usg=AFQjCNG9o_wkn2iRW8BaHyr69Ul6Ekfvfg

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-csharp/browse_thread/thread/46f55733d6e17a20-

Comment: Second link is broken, not sure what you wanted to show us :)